# Configure (gmail) email in python to prevent users from forwarding an email

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib, forwarding

I am using smtplib to send automatic emails (with Gmail) to a list of users. I want to prevent them from forwarding the emails they receive.

To my knowledge, there is no default setting on Gmail that makes all the emails sent from a given account not forwardable.  There is a *confidential mode*, which however must be set up for every new email and would prevent forwarding (and printing, downloading, etc...) for up to 5 years.

My question is: in the absence of a default setting on gmail that makes all emails not forwardable, can you suggest some python code that automatically selects the *confidential mode* for every email that is sent?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something this specific will require the Google-provided Gmail API, as that's not a standard feature of `SMTP`. Try looking [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), Google's developer QuickStart for Gmail.